# Apply SQL "LIKE" to bytes

Tags: sql, hibernate

I must create a DAO with hibernate that can work in a generic way, that means to execute some queries based on properties types.

My generic DAO works ok when filtering String properties of any class, it accepts "contains", "starts with", "ends with" using "like" restrictions:

Restrictions.like(propertyName, (String) value, getMatchMode());

The problem I have is that I need to also create a similar "contains", "starts with", "ends with" to bytes (byte[]) properties, the hibernate

SimpleExpression like(String propertyName, Object value)

api does not work (probably totally expected not to work), so I was thinking maybe I could convert the bytes stored in DB into a String, and then with a workaround apply the normal stringed Restrictions.like api.

The problem is that I think there's no standard way to convert bytes[] into String since there's no standard data type among DB platforms, I mean, Oracle uses "RAW", hsql uses "VARBINARY" and so on (Oracle uses its own RAWTOHEX for instance).

Or should any of you have an idea how to sort out the problem it will be very welcome.

Cheers.

///RGB

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could use `HEX` to convert `BINARY` to String. i.e.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  HEX(myBinaryField) LIKE 'abc%'`
```

In your Java code you could use some Base64 Encoder, which will convert bytes to string. Then you could just persist the Base64 encoded String and use normal `LIKE` queries. Maybe not the most efficient way, but it should work well.

Comment: thanks for helping, the problem is that I cannot change the schema.

Comment: What about something like this: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE HEX(myBinaryField) LIKE 'abc%'`. This works in MySQL. It converts the BINARY field to a String and then does a LIKE query using that String.

Comment: yes, but I have to create a query for each dialect, I guess there's no option :S Cheers!

Comment: There's one more way: Using `CAST(myBinaryField AS CHAR)` but the result consists of lot's of questionmarks in my tests.